# Ruby on rails. Callbacks, specifying changed attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, callback

I'm trying to send emails when a certain attribute changes in my model.

My model has a `string` which I set to `hired` `reject` `seen` and `notseen`.

For example, If the attribute gets changed to `reject` I want to send an email, and if it's changed to `hired` I want to send a different one.

In my model I have:

```
after_update :send_email_on_reject

def send_email_on_reject
    if status_changed?
      UserMailer.reject_notification(self).deliver
    end
  end
```

Which sends the email when the status gets changed regardless of what the status is. I don't know how to specify this. I have tried something like:

```
def send_email_on_reject
    if status_changed?
        if :status == "reject"
      UserMailer.reject_notification(self).deliver
        end
    end
  end
```

which just doesn't send the email.

I have been searching but cannot find any up to date similar questions/examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def send_email_on_reject
  if status_changed? && status == "reject"
    UserMailer.reject_notification(self).deliver 
  end
end
```

Comment: @Rob Hughes - Just to clarify what just happened - you were comparing a :status symbol to a string with the value "reject" which are always not equal. The real status attribute of your model is accessed by self.status, or simply status since you're in the scope of the current object.

Comment: This works perfectly thankyou. So simple but I couldn't find any examples in the docs. @BogdanAgafonov thankyou for explaining that.